# Search, Find, Print, Rename - PythonV2.7.5 String Extractor

Tags: python, string, search, printing

This is my first post on StackOverflow so I apologise if it is too vague. 
Essentially, I have LOTS of files that are outputted from a program, and I am trying to automate the process of collecting all the Data.

All I want is the values of a string to be returned in a printed format. Which I have managed to achieve. However, I want to also make a column on the newly printed file to tell me which file that string came from.

I've only been using python for about 6 hours ... so any help would be very appreciated !

Snippet of the file Content :

```
  GROWTH DIRECTION =         0  0  1
  SLICE SHIFT  5 =              0.00 ANGSTROMS
  LATTICE ENERGY =            -21.40 KCAL/MOL
  SLICE ENERGY =              -21.40 KCAL/MOL
  ATTACHMENT ENERGY =           0.00 KCAL/MOL
  SURFACE ENERGY =              0.00
  -------------------------------------------
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
# This script is to be used to pull out lines from strings. 
import re # Standard Regular expression module


lattE = open("TestFile.txt", "r") # opens the assigned file
lattEW = open("Lattice_Energies2.txt", "w") # Writes a new document to include all the lines that use LATTICE


for line in lattE: # looks through every line in the file 
    if re.match("(.*)(L)ATTICE(.*)", line): #searches the lines for LATTICE 
        print >>lattEW, line,  # Prints the lines
```

Current Output:

```
  LATTICE ENERGY =            -21.40 KCAL/MOL
  LATTICE ENERGY =            -21.40 KCAL/MOL
```

Comment: So, in your example you also want to print "TestFile.txt" string, right? Or is TestFile.txt already containing output from several files?

Comment: Please add the python version...

Comment: Also would be nice if you add a snippet of the file content.

Comment: @user1308345 I have attached a snippet of the text file. That is just the name of the file I am testing with

Comment: @Wind85 That is the Python version ? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @AlexAMP python version might be 2.7, 3.0, 3.4, 3.5

Comment: Oh! I am ever so sorry! This was written in 2.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative method ... that actually worked. Thanks @Gabor Fekete.

```
import fnmatch #Imports the synx for itteratively searching through Files 
import os 
import re #regex Expressions 
for file in os.listdir('/.'): #Goes through Files in Directory 
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.sum'): # Selects files with .sum extension 
        lattE = open(file,"r")  #opens said files 
        lattEW = open("Latt_En.txt", "a") #Amends Summary file
        for line in lattE: # Goes through file 
            if re.match("(.*)(L)ATTICE(.*)", line): #Searches for term LATTICE
                print >>lattEW, lattE.name, line, #Prints to LattEW file , name and line
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the file object's `name` attribute.

```
for line in lattE:
    if re.match("text", line):
        print lattE.name, line,
```

Comment: So it would be 

    lattE = open("*.txt", "r") ??

Comment: By writing `open(...)` the return value of this function creates a [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), it will have a `name` attribute which will contain the underlying file's name (the string you called the open function with)

Comment: AHHH!! That worked perfectly! 

Now how do I get it to go through the different number of files ... so let's say that I have test_file1.txt , test_file2.txt etc ?

Comment: You could iterate through the files in your folder or simply use another standard module called [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fnmatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

So I've been searching a bit further and found this really useful post [https://askubuntu.com/questions/352198/reading-all-files-from-a-directory][1]

And Tried to combine that with my existing code... and it doesn't seem to be printing to output file :|

```
import sys 
import glob
import errno
import re

path = '\*.sum' 
files = glob.glob(path)
lattEW = open("Lattice_En.txt", "a")
for name in files: # 'file' is a builtin type, 'name' is a less-ambiguous variable name.
    try:
        with open(name) as f: # No need to specify 'r': this is the default.
            sys.stdout.write(f.read())
        for line in name: # looks through every line in the file
                if re.match("(.*)(L)ATTICE(.*)", line): #searches the lines for LATTICE
                    print >>lattEW, name, line, 
    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR: # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
            raise # Propagate other kinds of IOError
```